# Clustered standard errors with texreg?

Tags: r, texreg

I'm trying to reproduce [this](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/webbooks/reg/chapter4/statareg4.htm) stata example and move from `stargazer` to `texreg`. The data is available [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjmuJiLg-bLAhWK8CYKHfSGCakQFggsMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdl.dropboxusercontent.com%2Fu%2F28526762%2FAPS%2Felemapi2.dta&usg=AFQjCNHo2xf6nVn6iJAwilMstoOCPj7C6Q&sig2=njn9r3WlM20orIA7oywnug).

To run the regression and get the se I run this code:

```
library(readstata13)
library(sandwich)
cluster_se <- function(model_result, data, cluster){
  model_variables   <- intersect(colnames(data), c(colnames(model_result$model), cluster))
  model_rows <- as.integer(rownames(model_result$model))
  data <- data[model_rows, model_variables]

  cl <- data[[cluster]]
  M <- length(unique(cl))
  N <- nrow(data)
  K <- model_result$rank
  dfc <- (M/(M-1))*((N-1)/(N-K))
  uj  <- apply(estfun(model_result), 2, function(x) tapply(x, cl, sum));
  vcovCL <- dfc*sandwich(model_result, meat=crossprod(uj)/N)
  sqrt(diag(vcovCL))
}
elemapi2 <- read.dta13(file = 'elemapi2.dta')
lm1 <- lm(formula = api00 ~ acs_k3 + acs_46 + full + enroll, data = elemapi2)
se.lm1 <- cluster_se(model_result = lm1, data = elemapi2, cluster = "dnum")

stargazer::stargazer(lm1, type = "text", style = "aer", se = list(se.lm1))

==========================================================
  api00                 
----------------------------------------------------------
  acs_k3                              6.954                 
                                      (6.901)                

acs_46                             5.966**                
                                   (2.531)                

full                               4.668***               
                                   (0.703)                

enroll                             -0.106**               
                                   (0.043)                

Constant                            -5.200                
                                    (121.786)               

Observations                         395                  
R2                                  0.385                 
Adjusted R2                         0.379                 
Residual Std. Error           112.198 (df = 390)          
F Statistic                61.006*** (df = 4; 390)        
----------------------------------------------------------
  Notes:              ***Significant at the 1 percent level.
**Significant at the 5 percent level. 
*Significant at the 10 percent level.
```

`texreg` produces this:

```
texreg::screenreg(lm1, override.se=list(se.lm1))    

========================
  Model 1    
------------------------
  (Intercept)    -5.20    
                 (121.79)   
acs_k3          6.95    
                (6.90)   
acs_46          5.97 ***
                (2.53)   
full            4.67 ***
                (0.70)   
enroll         -0.11 ***
                (0.04)   
------------------------
  R^2             0.38    
Adj. R^2        0.38    
Num. obs.     395       
RMSE          112.20    
========================
```

How can I fix the p-values?

Comment: See also section 5.5 of the texreg article in the Journal of Statistical Software for a basic example using ``sandwich`` and ``lmtest``. The updated paper is available here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/texreg/vignettes/v55i08.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot @PhilipLeifeld ! Great package! I just posted a follow up question about the confidence intervals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, notice that your usage of `as.integer` is dangerous and likely to cause problems once you use data with non-numeric rownames. For instance, using the built-in dataset `mtcars` whose rownames consist of car names, your function will coerce all rownames to `NA`, and your function will not work.

To your actual question, you can provide custom p-values to `texreg`, which means that you need to compute the corresponding p-values. To achieve this, you could compute the variance-covariance matrix, compute the test-statistics, and then compute the p-value manually, or you just compute the variance-covariance matrix and supply it to e.g. `coeftest`. Then you can extract the standard errors and p-values from there. Since I am unwilling to download any data, I use the `mtcars`-data for the following:

```
library(sandwich)
library(lmtest)
library(texreg)

cluster_se <- function(model_result, data, cluster){
  model_variables   <- intersect(colnames(data), c(colnames(model_result$model), cluster))
  model_rows <- rownames(model_result$model) # changed to be able to work with mtcars, not tested with other data
  data <- data[model_rows, model_variables]
  cl <- data[[cluster]]
  M <- length(unique(cl))
  N <- nrow(data)
  K <- model_result$rank
  dfc <- (M/(M-1))*((N-1)/(N-K))
  uj  <- apply(estfun(model_result), 2, function(x) tapply(x, cl, sum));
  vcovCL <- dfc*sandwich(model_result, meat=crossprod(uj)/N)
}

lm1 <- lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + disp, data = mtcars)
vcov.lm1 <- cluster_se(model_result = lm1, data = mtcars, cluster = "carb")

standard.errors <- coeftest(lm1, vcov. = vcov.lm1)[,2]
p.values <- coeftest(lm1, vcov. = vcov.lm1)[,4]

texreg::screenreg(lm1, override.se=standard.errors, override.p = p.values)
```

And just for completeness sake, let's do it manually:

```
t.stats <- abs(coefficients(lm1) / sqrt(diag(vcov.lm1)))
t.stats
(Intercept)         cyl        disp 
  38.681699    5.365107    3.745143
```

These are your t-statistics using the cluster-robust standard errors. The degree of freedom is stored in `lm1$df.residual`, and using the built in functions for the t-distribution (see e.g. `?pt`), we get:

```
manual.p <- 2*pt(-t.stats, df=lm1$df.residual)
manual.p
 (Intercept)          cyl         disp 
1.648628e-26 9.197470e-06 7.954759e-04
```

Here, `pt` is the distribution function, and we want to compute the probability of observing a statistic at least as extreme as the one we observe. Since we testing two-sided and it is a symmetric density, we first take the left extreme using the negative value, and then double it. This is identical to using `2*(1-pt(t.stats, df=lm1$df.residual))`. Now, just to check that this yields the same result as before:

```
all.equal(p.values, manual.p)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 4):

## Robust Standard Errors with `texreg` are easy: just pass the coeftest directly!

This has become much easier since the question was last answered: it appears you can now just pass the coeftest with the desired variance-covariance matrix directly. Downside: you lose the goodness of fit statistics (such as R^2 and number of observations), but depending on your needs, this may not be a big problem

### How to include robust standard errors with texreg

```
> screenreg(list(reg1, coeftest(reg1,vcov = vcovHC(reg1, 'HC1'))), 
      custom.model.names = c('Standard Standard Errors', 'Robust Standard Errors'))

=============================================================
             Standard Standard Errors  Robust Standard Errors
-------------------------------------------------------------
(Intercept)  -192.89 ***               -192.89 *             
              (55.59)                   (75.38)              
x               2.84 **                   2.84 **            
               (0.96)                    (1.04)              
-------------------------------------------------------------
R^2             0.08                                         
Adj. R^2        0.07                                         
Num. obs.     100                                            
RMSE          275.88                                         
=============================================================
*** p < 0.001, ** p < 0.01, * p < 0.05
```

To generate this example, I created a dataframe with heteroscedasticity, see below for full runnable sample code:

```
require(sandwich);
require(texreg);

set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100);
df$y <- 1 + 0.5*df$x + 5*100:1*rnorm(100)

reg1 <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)
```